# How to set a UILocatNotification to fire everyday at 9 am

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I need to set a UILocatNotification to fire everyday at 9 am. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What've you done so far?

Comment: everything is done I just need to know how to format the firedate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[formatter setDateFormat:[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 
                                                         options:0
                                                          locale:nil]];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

notification.fireDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2010-10-21 09:00:00"];
notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
```